# angularJS: ui-router equivalent to $location.search

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using the following to do paging in my datagrid:

```
$location.search('page', page);
```

where page is the current page number.

Then I listen to the following event:

```
   $scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function(next, current) {
            $scope.currentPage = $routeParams.page ? Number($routeParams.page) : 1;

            $scope.search();
        });
```

That triggers a call to a search() method on my scope after updating the currentPage that is in the URL.

How would I translate that to states with ui-router ? The $routeUpdate is no longer triggered since I'm using a state manager instead of routes.

My route is now defined in the state provider as such:

```
   $stateProvider
        .state('mandats', {
            url: '/domiciliations/mandats',
            templateUrl: 'domiciliations/views/mandats.html',
            controller: 'mandatsCtrl'
        })
```

Comment: What is `$stateProvider`?

Comment: it's part of ui-router plugin of AngularJS. It provides state management.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up listening to the $locationChangeSuccess event instead and that solved it.

Comment: Note that `$locationChangeSuccess` will be fired when you go to another page/route, while `$routeUpdate` will not. I needed to add additional check for `$location.path()` into the handler to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I would try to  use the [controller](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/State-Manager) (mandatsCtrl in your example) to put that logic. the view controller will be called with every parameter change, and you could inject the $stateParams into it to get the page #

other similar option to explore is the [view controllers](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) which is what I've used at some point

last, since $stateParams is injectable, you might want to inject it to your custom-built directive and use it there straight