# Why controller doesn't respond on route update?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I would like preserve instance of controller without reloading. I set `reloadOnSearch` to false and I manage route change in my controller. Here is the code.

This is example of my link `<a href="products/page/2">next</a>`. I have defined following module.

```
angular.module('app.products', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/:section/:view/:number', {
                templateUrl: 'tpl/table.html',
                controller: 'ProductsCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'productsCtrl',
                reloadOnSearch: false
            });
}])
.controller('ProductsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', ProductsCtrl]);
```

*Controller*

```
function ProductsCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $location) {

    $scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function () {
        console.log("routeUpdate");
    });

}
```

But the controller doesn't respond on changed route and text is not written to console output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the angular jargon, "search" refers only to the query string parameters part of the URL. For instance: `?key=value&page=42`

And the "path" refers to the URL without that query string. Here `/products/page/2` is a path.

When setting `reloadOnSearch: false` you're telling angular not to reload the view and the associated controller when **only** the query string parameters changes.

- So if the path changes, for instance you navigate from `/products/page/2` to `/products/page/3`, then the view will still be reloaded. No `$routeUpdate` will be fired because there is no need for that. You'll get the new parameters from `$routeParams` when your controller initialization function is called again.
- However if the path doesn't change, but only the query string parameters do change. For instance when you navigate from `/products?page=2` to `/products?page=3`. Then the view will not be reloaded and a `$routeUpdate` will be broadcast.

So the solution here would be to define `page` as a query string parameter instead of a path parameter:

```
angular.module('app.products', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/:section', {
                templateUrl: 'tpl/table.html',
                controller: 'ProductsCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'productsCtrl',
                reloadOnSearch: false
            });
}])
.controller('ProductsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', ProductsCtrl]);
```

Controller:

```
function ProductsCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $location) {
    $scope.setupView = function setupView(section, page) {
        // Setup you view here
        // ...
    };

    $scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function () {
        // This is called when only the query parameters change. E.g.: ?page=2
        $scope.setupView($routeParams.section, $routeParams.page)
    });

    // This one is called when the the path changes and the view is reloaded.
    $scope.setupView($routeParams.section, $routeParams.page)
}
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me, but this one did:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278951/angularjs-ui-router-equivalent-to-location-search

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $routeUpdate, try to use $routeChangeSuccess.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (scope, next, current) {
    console.log("Your text goes here.");
});
```

You can use next and current to check your previous and next route.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Listening on `routeChangeSuccess` doesn't preserve the same instance of the controller.