# Preserving controller on path change

Tags: angularjs, navigation

Currently, I'm using URL like

```
/order
/order?id=123
/orderitem/123
/orderitem/123/id=456
```

where there's one controller for the first two cases and another one for the last two cases. Each controller shows an entity list and optionally (when an `id` is given) details of the selected entity.

I'd like to switch to a more logical schema like

```
/order
/order/123
/order/123/item
/order/123/item/456
```

without changing the controllers. According to this [comment by misko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908379/why-controller-doesnt-respond-on-route-update#comment40556584_25910091), the controller instance doesn't get preserved on "path" (rather than just "search") changes.

Is there a way to avoid reinstantiating the controller?

I'm using no ui-router, would it help?

Comment: Would it be a single state with optional parameters, or an state with a nested state whith that param?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2993

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro No idea, I've never used ui-router. I guess, two states, just like my two controllers. One with optional `orderId`, the other with mandatory `orderId` and optional `itemId`.

Answer (score 0):

With ui-router, you can define which controller is used for which state:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('order', {
        url: '/order/:orderId',
        controller: 'OrderCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'orders.html'
    }).state('order.item', {
        url: '/item/:itemId',
        templateUrl: 'items.html',
        controller: 'ItemsCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

Then in your template files, you can link to each state (with an input id if needed):

```
<a ui-sref="order">/order</a>
<a ui-sref="order({id:1})">/order/1</a>
<a ui-sref="order({id:1}).item">/order/1/item</a>
<a ui-sref="order({id:1}).item({id:1})">/order/1/item/1</a>
```

Comment: OK, I can specify the same controller for `/order` and `/order/123`, but when transitioning between them, will the controller *instance* be preserved?

Comment: @maaartinus If the app is wired correctly, yes it should.